# SQLite / Python database retrieval and comparison

Tags: python, sqlite

At the moment, I have a database which contains username, password, etc.
I am wishing to look into the database to check if duplicates are in there.

```
con = lite.connect('userInfo.db')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE LOWER(Username) = LOWER(?)", (newID,))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    if len(rows)!=0:
        return "Duplicate detected"
```

Here is my code at the moment. `newID` is a new name and I wish to check if there are any existing entries in the database with the same name.

My question is - is the way I am doing it in my code a good idea? I'm mainly concerned with my approach. Should I be using something other than `fetchall()` ?

Thank you for your time! :)
P.S. This is for a website application.

Comment: To save memory, consider replacing `fetchall()` with `fetchone()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to do exactly what you asked for - find out if a given `username` already exists:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.execute ("""
              CREATE TABLE users (
                  uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                  username TEXT UNIQUE,
                  email TEXT UNIQUE );
             """)

test_users = (
    {'username':"Alice",    'email':"Alice@mail.com"},
    {'username':"Billy",    'email':"Billy@mail.com"},
    {'username':"Charles",  'email':"Charles@mail.com"},
    {'username':"Dick",     'email':"Dick@mail.com"},
    {'username':"Emily",    'email':"Emily@mail.com"},
    {'username':"Faramir",  'email':"Faramir@mail.com"},
)

for user in test_users:
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, email) VALUES (?,?)",
                 (user['username'],user['email'])
                )

result = conn.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username='Alice'")
number_of_Alices = result.next()[0] # number_of_Alices will be 1
```

Since all you want is a `COUNT` this is adequate.

---

Really, though, you shouldn't be enforcing the uniqueness of the usernames yourself. Let the database do that for you by specifying the field to be either `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY`.

If you try to insert `"Alice", "alice@wonderland.com"` after creating the database like above, this will get you an sqlite3.IntegrityError:

```
>>> conn.execute("""INSERT INTO users (username, email)
...                     VALUES ("Alice", "alice@wonderland.com");""")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
sqlite3.IntegrityError: column username is not unique
```

To detect this, try to run the `INSERT` and detect whether it fails.

```
try:
    conn.execute("""INSERT INTO users (username, email)
                    VALUES ("Alice", "alice@wonderland.com");""")
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    print ("Username 'Alice' was already taken.")
```

Incidentally, be very careful with using the upper/lowercase functions. Does `"Главное в новостях".lower()` mean what you think it means?

---

Since you mention this is for a webapp, I'll just remind you to store your passwords as [*salted* hashes of the password, using unique salts for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database) (never as plain text!), and to guard against SQL injection by using the `(?,?,?,?,...)` placeholders for SQL queries, not the `(%s,%s) % (var1, var2)` string interpolation method.

To quote the [sqlite3 documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html):

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python
>   variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string
>   operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program
>   vulnerable to an SQL injection attack.
>
> Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put ? as a
>   placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple
>   of values as the second argument to the cursor’s execute() method.
>   (Other database modules may use a different placeholder, such as %s or
>   :1.) For example:

If you don't do this, then someone could request the username `Robert Menzies; DROP TABLE users;` with [hilarious results](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Thank you for your fine explanation. Greatly appreciated. Just out of curiosity, what does `Robert Menzies; DROP TABLE users;` actually do and why? Thans!

Comment: Actually the name would need to be `Robert Menzies); DROP TABLE users;`. Then if your query is like `"INSERT INTO users VALUES  (%s)" % username`, then after the variable substitution you will have `"INSERT INTO users VALUES (Robert Menzies); DROP TABLE users;` - which will insert `Robert Menzies` into the `users` table, then **delete the entire `users` table.**

Comment: This is called an SQL injection attack, and is possible because the `;` character ends an SQL command and begins a new one. **One** of the things you have to do is escape `;` characters in user input so this doesn't happen. Using the recommended practice - `(?,?,?...)` placeholders - in the `sqlite3` documentation will guard against this attack and more.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the field in SQLite to unique which will prevent duplicate entries in the first place.

Comment: What happens if a duplicate entry is detected?

Comment: @Vincent if you set Username colummn to unique and a insert is made into the Users table with an already existing Username it will result in a fail. e.g. there will never be any duplications in the first place.

Comment: So would my program essentially 'crash' ? Sorry, I'm new and just starting out at coding. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will get a `SQLite3.OperationalError` which says "something went wrong". If duplicate usernames could be reasonably expected you can catch the exception using a `try... except` block and recover. If duplicate usernames should never be attempted in the first place it's OK to crash.

Comment: And the `username` field should really be `PRIMARY KEY`. That said, using a separate `user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` and `username TEXT UNIQUE` is probably a better way of doing things - that way strange characters in the `username` won't cause bugs (will your code handle the username "Главное в новостях" correctly?) and users will be free to change their usernames at will (since it's not being used as a key anywhere else.)

Comment: I'm trying to make a web application and it is essentially a 'sign up page' - making sure there is no duplication of usernames. I will try the `try... except` thing now.

As for the strange characters, I added a check using `if newID.isalnum() is False:` so that should not pose a problem.

Comment: @Vincent: `if newID.isalnum()` is a bad idea. There are legitimate reasons for people to use non-ASCII usernames. What happens if a Frenchman wants to join your site? `"Éponine Thénardier".isalnum() == False`!

Comment: Actually even `"Robert Menzies".isalnum()` is false (because of the space character.)